# Pick an object up and then drop it

Tags: animation, physics

so I have read a few similar articles but I can't find a solution. Essentially I want to animate this iso shape to do several actions and then in a split second have it leave my keyframes and have gravity AND inertia take full affect and fall to the ground motionless.

So far I have set my iso to be a child of an empty and then animated that empty. I had also setup the physics prior to this and had defined active and passive properties. Lastly I keyframed the influence from 100% to 0% ...

The iso follows all the keyframed movements of the empty and when the influence gets turned off it goes back to its start position and just sticks there...

Does anyone have some advice?

[image]

Comment: so, instead of using an empty, why don't you animate the object itself and the moment before you want it to be affected by physics, keyframe the Rigid Body Animated option?

Comment: Hey, thanks moonboots! That sounds super interesting! Could you explain a little bit further and perhaps add in a screenshot?

Seems like this could be the answer.

Comment: I just animated the iso and when I uncheck the "animated" option nothing happens, it just hang in space. When I check it back on it then snaps back into the assigned keyframes.

Comment: keyframe the 2 following frames: the one just before it is supposed to be affected by the physics (Animated ON), and the following one, when it is affected by the physics (Animated OFF)

Comment: Ok, that is awesome! Can you add this as an answer? Then I will give you the completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an empty, you could animate the object itself. To do so, keyframe the 2 following frames: The one just before it is supposed to be affected by the physics (*Animated* ON), and the following one, when it is supposed to be affected by the physics (*Animated* OFF).